# Can't get new TextArea value and save it

Tags: c#, textarea

I have a textarea which runs on server side. I am writing some text into the area and then i want to save it in a textfile by clicking a save button with the following code

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string v = codearea.InnerHtml.ToString();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["path"].ToString() + txtpath.Text , v);
}

<textarea id="codearea" name="codearea" cols="200" runat="server">
```

When i am debugging the variable v is still empty. Any help? I have to mention that the text area is in an .ascx page

Comment: What is the value of `code area.InnerHtml`?  What is the value of `codearea`?  What is the type of `codearea`?  Where is it populated with data?  Is it being overwritten elsewhere in the page lifecycle?

Comment: Can you post the markup of the textarea control?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `codearea.Value` instead.

**UPDATE:** I have tested using `InnerHtml` as well, and it works fine. We'll need to see the HTML code for the textarea in your case.

**TEST CASE:**

```
 <textarea runat="server" id="test"></textarea>
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

When I click `Button1` both the `InnerHtml` and `Value` are correct.